# High Sierra Combo Update 10.13.4 to 10.13.6

Tags: high-sierra

The combo update will not install and provides the error message that " This volume does not meet the requirements for this update"

I have 62GB spare in 121GM HD.....

What are the "requirements"? What do I have to do to the HD to make this work... It is an Apple update after all.. not a third party item

Comment: Odd... You **DO** have macOS 10.13.x, correct? Have you tried updating via the MacApp store?

Comment: What is your hardware?

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to 10.13.5 and from there to 10.13.6? That's how I did it and it worked fine. The only issue now may be finding the updates.

Comment: Thanks @jmh ,
Found 13.5, then added 13.6 then Xcode
Yeh!!!!!!!

Comment: @rodmcmahon: If I post my comment as an answer will you accept it?